# What are the best practices for using rsocket securely?

Tags: security, rsocket

what are the best practices for using rsocket securely (authentication, authorization). Is this something that rsocket is opinionated about or work that others have done to build on top of rsocket?

Answer (score 3):

RSocket is not opinionated on security. It is simply facilitating the communication between the endpoints. It is up to you as the developer to build whatever security mechanisms you need on top. This could be things like: SSL (depending on your underlying RSocket transport), access / secret keys, OAuth, etc.

Comment: it seems like using an authenticated transport is not possible in the current implementations (see my comment on the forums: https://community.netifi.com/t/using-transport-layer-authentication/221)